# Qt Q_OBJECT creates linker errors in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, linker, lnk2001

I'm trying to get Qt to work with Visual Studio 2010. I've built a working program that I can run in the debugger. However, when I try to add the Q_OBJECT macro to my class, it generates a bunch of linker errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: qt_poop, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2012/08/05 12:58:56.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\qt_poop.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  GLViewer.cpp
1>  Window.cpp
1>  main.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>Link:
1>  LINK : c:\Users\abral\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\qt_poop\Win32\Debug\\qt_poop.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>GLViewer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall GLViewer::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@GLViewer@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>GLViewer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall GLViewer::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@GLViewer@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>GLViewer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall GLViewer::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@GLViewer@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>c:\Users\abral\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\qt_poop\Win32\Debug\\qt_poop.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:07.50
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've seen some similar problems raised by others and it seems to have something to do with the compiler and moc and a bunch of other really complicated technical stuff that my beginner brain can't quite comprehend yet. Also, a lot of it seems geared towards people who are using a command line to configure their compilers, but I'm using VS and I'd really like to keep it that way (basically I just want to be able to press the green arrow and see my program - that's all). So... if someone could explain to me in as simple a way as possible how to configure Visual Studio to do whatever linking or compiling or whatnot that it needs to do to accomplish this, I'll be eternally grateful.

Comment: QT creator has a green arrow, and is well suited for writing code with QT. Just sayin'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling a simple Qt "Hello World!" application within Visual Studio 2010 Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031512/compiling-a-simple-qt-hello-world-application-within-visual-studio-2010-expre)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to compile Qt with VS2010.
http://thomasstockx.blogspot.in/2011/03/qt-472-in-visual-studio-2010.html
Follow all the steps he said, probably this may help you resolve your issues. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you add the Q_OBJECT to a class then make sure, you run `qmake`! I worked with the Creator, but i had really weird errors, when i didn't do that, before trying to compile some code, containing a class extending QObject, with a Q_OBJECT macro.